# Real time depth measurement system

Tags: raspicam

I want to design real time depth measurement system. so, which type of camera is compatible for Raspberry Pi 3 to get depth.

Comment: Why use a camera for depth detection? what about using SONAR or RADAR?

Comment: Or a [Kinect](https://github.com/xxorde/librekinect).

Answer (score 2):

You're unlikely, I think, to be able to do this with any Pi model other than the [Compute Module](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/compute-module/).

The Compute Module includes two ZIF connectors which can be used to attach two [Raspberry Pi camera modules](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module-v2/). The bandwidth available to these cameras is [substantial](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51715/what-is-the-speed-of-the-camera-serial-interface-csi-and-its-cable), and the compute module is [*just about* capable](http://www.argondesign.com/case-studies/2014/oct/21/stereo-depth-perception-raspberry-pi/) of rendering depth maps from the data produced.

The Pi 3 has only 1 CSI interface, so you can only attach 1 Pi camera board, which is of no use for stereoscopic vision. You could try connecting 2 USB cameras, but given the limited bandwidth ([circa 480Mb/s](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22685/usb-bandwidth-for-the-rpi-model-b)) and unpredictable timing of USB cameras I think you're going to have a hard time getting enough synchronised data from them to create a practical depth map.